# MySite search not updating

Tags: my-site, mysites

I inherited SharePoint support and have been receiving issues of people updating their MySite profiles with new pictures, updating a phone number etc etc, but when you search for those people the information shown on the search page is the old information. Clicking and viewing their actual MySite shows the correct information.

What could be causing this incorrect information to be fed into the search?

Comment: How is the search scope configured? Is the mysite url listed with both http(s) and sps3 prefixes?

Comment: Just http://url/pages/default.aspx

Comment: Are you sure, because that would just update the start page. Have you configured User Profile Sync?

Comment: I inherited the support and do not know how it was setup. I am in chat if you would like to join me.